# select like que retorne uma sting sem quebra de linha

Tags: mysql, sql

estou usando a seguinte consulta:

```
select distinct con_destinatario from tab_conhecimento where con_destinatario like '%CALLE%' order by con_destinatario;
```

e obtenho varios resultados desse tipo:

```
    A.S. OPORTUNIDADES Y NEGOCIOS S.R.L.
    CALLE TTE. ROJAS SILVA CASI REDUCCION MELODIA
    VILLA HAYES - PARAGUAY
```

Gostaria que a consulta considera-se somente a primeira linha antes da quebra de linha alguém se habilita?

Comment: No banco deve estar gravado um carriage return , um replace deve resolver, REPLACE(col, CHAR(13, 10), '')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CONSEGUI ASSIM:

```
select distinct con_destinatario from tab_conhecimento where con_destinatario like '%CALLE%' AND con_destinatario NOT LIKE '%
%CALLE%' order by con_destinatario;
```

Obrigado.